# move_group plan for 2 or more waypoints then execute

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want to move arm to pose1 and pose2, the straightforward way is

```
move_group.setStartState(*group.getCurrentState());
move_group.setPoseTarget(pose1);
move_group.plan(plan1);
move_group.execute(plan1);
move_group.setStartState(*group.getCurrentState());
move_group.setPoseTarget(pose2);
move_group.plan(plan2);
move_group.execute(plan2);
```

The problem is that if plan1 succeeds, and plan2 fails, plan1 is still executed. Is there a way to first check plan1 and plan2? If both succeed, then execute the plans.

I saw the argument of setPoseTargets() can be a list of poses, but the plan will only choose one randomly from the list as the goal...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356190/move_group-plan-for-2-or-more-waypoints-then-execute/) by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2020-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following works. ([reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/lZL2HTjLu-k))

```
#include<moveit/robot_trajectory/robot_trajectory.h>
#include<moveit/robot_state/robot_state.h>   

 group.setStartState(*group.getCurrentState());
 group.setPoseTarget(target_pose);
 success = group.plan(plan); 

 moveit::core::RobotModelConstPtr robot_model=group.getRobotModel();
 robot_trajectory::RobotTrajectory trajectory(robot_model, planning_group);
 trajectory.setRobotTrajectoryMsg(*(group.getCurrentState()),plan.trajectory_);
 
 group.setStartState(*trajectory.getLastWayPointPtr());
 group.setPoseTarget(target_pose2);
 success2 = group.plan(plan2); 

 if(success and success2){
    success = group.execute(plan);
    if(success)
     success2 = group.execute(plan2);
 }
```

---

Originally posted by [xibeisiber](https://answers.ros.org/users/54937/xibeisiber/) with karma: 137 on 2020-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0